# Is there such a thing as a 'IS IN' query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Silk_Skey   Name
1   Black White Checks Yellow Arms
2   Black Crimson Stripes
3   Crimson Yellow Stripes

Sub Colour  Major Colour
Black   Black
White   White
Yellow  Yellow
Crimson Red

MajorColour_Skey    Major Colour
1   Black
2   White
3   Yellow
4   Red
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
ID  Silk_Skey   MajorColour_Skey
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   2   1
5   2   4
6   3   3
7   3   4
```

What I need to do is create a linked table matching all the colours from the 3 tables and break down the silks names so I would show 4 lines in the new table) see SQL below. My boss has advised me to use a 'IS IN' query but I have no idea what that is can you help?

```
SELECT s.Silks_Skey, mc.MajorColour_Skey
FROM Silks s  INNER JOIN SubColour sc  on sc.SubColour **'IS IN HERE'** s.SilksName
INNER JOIN MajorColour mc
ON sc.MajorColour = mc.MajorColour
```

Comment: Yeah, it's called [in](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+in&aq=f&oq=sql+in&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j65j5j60.1266j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: from your description it sounds like the s.silkname is a varchar column that may contain multiple colors that you want to match against the color name field? If this is the case you will need to wild card search otherwise a simple IN will work if you have the color ids as a FK

Comment: I have edited my post above, I hope this helps because I don't understand what your suggestions are telling me. Thanks

Comment: Your boss is wrong, due to the way the data is stored you cannot use IN.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IN`

```
AND table.column IN ('a','b','c')
```

or

```
AND table.column IN (1,2,3)
```

or if you're looking for a string like something you can do

```
AND table.column LIKE '%word'  -- table.column ends with 'word'
AND table.column LIKE 'word%'  -- table.column starts with 'word'
AND table.column LIKE '%word%' -- table.column has 'word' anywhere in the column
```

Comment: I have edited my post above, I hope this helps because I don't understand what your suggestions are telling me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, you need to do string manipulation because you are trying to compare one color to a list of colors in a string.

The `like` operator can do this.  Try this `on` clause:

```
on ' '+ s.SilksName +' ' like '% '+sc.SubColour+' %'
```

This checks to see if a given color (`sc.SubColour`) in in the list (`s.SilksName`).  For instance, if you have a list like 'RED GREEN' this will match either '%RED%' or '%GREEN%'.

The purpose of concatenating white space is to avoid partial-word matches.  For instance, "blue-green" would match both "blue" and "green" without the delimiters.

The following query returns 7 rows, which seems to be correct (3 for the first row in silks and 2 for each of the other two):

```
with silks as (
      select 1 as silks_skey, 'Black White Checks Yellow Arms' as silksname union all
      select 2, 'Black Crimson Stripes' union all
      select 3, 'Crimson Yellow Stripes'
     ),
     subcolour as (
      select 'black' as subcolour, 'black' as majorcolour union all
      select 'white', 'white' union all
      select 'yellow', 'yellow' union all
      select 'crimson', 'red'
     ),
     MajorColour as (
      select 1 as MajorColour_skey, 'black' as MajorColour union all
      select 2, 'white' union all
      select 3, 'yellow' union all
      select 4, 'red'
     )
SELECT s.Silks_Skey, mc.MajorColour_Skey
FROM Silks s  INNER JOIN SubColour sc  on ' ' + s.SilksName + ' ' like '% ' + sc.SubColour + ' %'
INNER JOIN MajorColour mc
ON sc.MajorColour = mc.MajorColour
```

Comment: What's the purpose of concatenating whitespace either side of `s.SilksName`? Also I'm not sure I'd agree with calling it "string manipulation"; you're comparing strings, you're not really manipulating them.

Comment: I have edited my post above, I hope this helps because I don't understand what your suggestions are telling me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Gordon With your help the query works but I am not getting the amount I was expecting. I got 4 rows and not 17

Answer (score 1):

This is a design doomed to poor performance and awkward and painful to write queries. If your database will never be large, then it may be workable, but if it will be large, you cannot use this design structure and hope to have good performance because you will not be able to properly use indexes.  Personally I would add a silk colors table related to the silks table and store the colors indivudally. One of the first rules of database design is never store more than one piece of informatino in a field. You are storing a list which always means you need a related table to have effective use of the database.

One clue to a bad (and over time usually unworkable)database design is if you need to join using functions or caluations of any type or if you need to use wildcards at the start of a phrase in a like clause. Fix this now and things will be much smoother, maintenance will take less time and performacne will be better. There is no upside to your current structure at all.

You may need to take a bit of extra time to parse and store the silk names by individual color, but the time you save in querying the database will be significant becasue you can now make use of a join and then use indexes. Search for fn_split and you will see a method of spliting the silk names into individual colors that you can use when you insert the records.

If you foolishly decide to retain the current structure, then look into using fuilltext search. It wil be faster than using a like clause with a wildcard as the first character.

Comment: Hi HLGEM

There are 22 thousand different silk combinations at least so this was the best way forward.

Thanks

Comment: The more combinations, the worse trying parsing at select time is going to be. Your design is irretrevably flawed. You choose to not think about what you were going to do with the data at design time and now you are going to pay the price because there is no good way to join to your data. Ease of development is dead last in consideration in designing a database because what matters is data integrity and performance and security. And as you found out ease of development at one place means more pain at another. Redesiging is your best option. This problem cannot effectively be solved without it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want to do is split the `Name` field on spaces and then for each one of those values which is contained in the colours table (joined on the sub-colour given that major colours are valid sub-colours too) you want one entry in a new table. Problem is that there is no intrinsic T-SQL function for splitting strings. To do that your best bet is to visit [Erland Sommarskog's](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) definitive answer on how to do this.

An alternative, and one which is not very neat and may or may not work, is to use the CONTAINS keyword in your predicate. However in order to achieve this you need to use full text indexing 
and I suspect using Erland's excellent giudes on splitting strings and arrays in SQL will be more appropriate and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer folks, thanks for all your ideas.

```
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]

UNION ALL

Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0

ORDER BY S.[Silks_Skey]
```